# Heat dissipation on high power resistor

Tags: resistors, heatsink

A resistor (~1 cm x 1 cm x 4 cm) with I = 5 A and V = 10 V (P = 50 W) is perfectly attached (on the 1 cm x 4 cm side) to a flat copper piece with known thickness, D = 5 mm (no fins). Ambient T is 20°C.

Assuming the heat 
uniform over the copper piece, what should its area (A) be to cool down the resistors temperature at <30°C?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to electronics.SE! Please understand that to help you, we'll need you to at least deliver an approach or an attempt at solution! We can't be doing other people's homework :)

Comment: Hello, it really is not a homework. I need this for a project (to cool down my resistors). You are right though, I should have asked this another way.
I just need to know what kind of equation I should use. I am just confused by several relations (q=m*c*delT, q=h*a*delT, dT/dt=-k(T-Ta),...). Just need hint where I am?

Comment: should I use the convection equation q=ha(Tc-Ta) where Tc is the copper temperature and Ta is ambient temperature and q is power (J/s)? If so, what is q then? it can't be simply IV(=50 W), am I right? I am confused

Comment: Given Ali's good answer, just search for 0.2C/W heatsinks. and either buy one or copy its topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple formula. The result will depend on how the copper plate is positioned relative to gravity field, horizontally or vertically, is it really in a free air, or if there are obstacles to airflow.  And the shape of copper plate (aspect ratio) will matter.

To get some ideas of reasonable values of thermal impedance of various sink geometries, take a look at this article, "[Calculating heat sinks](http://www.giangrandi.ch/electronics/thcalc/thcalc.shtml)"

You are actually asking to dissipate 50 W with delta_T of 10 deg.C. This is equivalent to thermal impedance of 0.2C/W. This kind of impedance can be achieved only with multi-fin sink design under forced air, like a CPU heat sink. The value of 0.2 C/W can't be achieved with a simple copper plate in free air, maybe a massive heat spreader based on efficient heat pipes can help, but I doubt it.

Today the design of heat management configurations is usually done using expensive software such as [FloTERM](https://www.mentor.com/products/mechanical/flotherm/flotherm/),  which uses solid thermal models for heat conduction, and associated airflow models for convection around the solid surfaces. It is pretty complicated, and thus expensive.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.So, I was right about the convection equation q=ha(Tc-Ta) -> Thermal impedance=1/(ha)=delta_T/q